# Issues in as3 with adding objects from different classes

Tags: actionscript-3, external

So, I'm trying to add an object to my stage via code. I've set it up between to files, Cosmo1, and Mass1. I have Mass1 set as my class directory in flash, and the code for Mass1 is as follows:

```
package com.mass.basics1
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;
public class Mass1 extends MovieClip
{


    public function Mass1()
    {
        var Cosmo:Cosmo1 = new Cosmo1();
        stage.addChild(Cosmo1);
        Cosmo.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
        Cosmo.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
    }
}
}
```

And this is the code for Cosmo1:

```
package  com.mass.basics1
{  
import flash.display.MovieClip;  
public class Cosmo1 extends MovieClip  
{  
    public function Cosmo1()  
    {  

    }  
}  
}
```

Now, all my directories are set correctly, and I'm not receiving any errors, however it's simply not adding my object. The object is in my library with a symbol name, and a class name of directory.Cosmo1, so I really can't see what the issue is.

Comment: Can you tell us the error/warning that you're getting?

Comment: Like I said above, I'm not experiencing a warning of any kind.

Comment: You've set up a document class in the Flash IDE, right?

Comment: Yes, and I just found the issue, it seems that when I was creating a symbol from my .png image of Cosmo, it was turning into just a registry dot, so it was effectively invisible. I have resolved this issue now, sorry for the waste of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add your instance as a child of your stage. But in your code, your add the class name.

You mistake might come from the fact your instance name start with a uppercase letter. Code conventions usually tell to start instance names with a lowercase letter.

Here is an updated version of your code:

```
package com.mass.basics1
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;

    public class Mass1 extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Mass1()
        {
            var cosmo:Cosmo1 = new Cosmo1();
            stage.addChild(cosmo);
            cosmo.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
            cosmo.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, well I tried you code, and it didn't change much, although the organization is better. In the properties of my object Cosmo1, I left the base class empty and only filled in the class section, should I fill in the class section?

Comment: Is your class `Mass1` instantiated and added to the stage as well?

Comment: Yikes, I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Mass1 is just an external file saying Cosmo1 should be added to the stage. My class directory in the property panels of flash is set to Mass1.

Comment: I think you have to create an instance of `Mass1` somewhere for your code to be run (`var mass:Mass1 = new Mass1();`) but I'm not a user of FlashCS so I can really help you on that.

Comment: I just found the issue, it seems that when I was creating a symbol from my .png image of Cosmo, it was turning into just a registry dot, so it was effectively invisible. I have resolved this issue now, sorry for the waste of time.